# "1 alert" is on the next to "About This Mac"

Tags: macos, mojave

I am using MacBook Air 11' Early 2015 and macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

I have recently noticed the message "1 alert" appeared next to "About This Mac" in Apple menu.
[image: 1 alert on apple menu]

There seems to be nothing strange in "About This Mac" dialog.

I guess that this happpened after running some executable(s) in `/System/Library/CoreServices`. 
I tried logging as root (saw [Silencing the Memory slot utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37801/silencing-the-memory-slot-utility)), but it persists.

Any idea to get rid of this alert? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have macOS Mojave 10.14.6 on my MacBook Pro (2017, 15-inch), and I see the same message, which persists after rebooting.  I do occasionally run CoreServices apps directly.

I'm no systems expert, but it makes me think that:

- A CoreServices app added itself to a startup folder upon first launch.  (e.g. the LaunchAgents, LaunchDaemons, or Startup Items folders in one of the Library folders)  It may also show up in the Activity Monitor.
- A Terminal command may reveal alerts that can't display in About This Mac screens.  (I tried "mail" for my own account, but there were no messages.)